# Factor analysis doesn't work with categorical variable analysis

Tags: r, psych, factor-analysis

I have a problem with (explanatory) factor analysis, by using `psych` package.
My data contains three 1-4 categories variables and four 1-5 variables (and each has NA category).

```
  PARTY1 ELECTION1 CONGRESS1 WASTE1 NOMATT1 INFLU1 COMPLEX1
   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
1      4         4         4      5       5      1        1
2      2         3         3      5       5      2        2
3      3         4         3      5       5      2        5
4      4         4         4      5       5      5        1
5      1         4         3      5       5      3        4
6      3         3         3      4       5      2        2
```

I run the following command to perform polychoric correlation FA.

```
EFA.2009w1 <- fa(data.2009.wave1, nfactors = 3, rotate = "promax", 
                 fm="wls", cor = "poly", scores = TRUE, use="complete.obs")
```

But I got an error message that says

> polychoric(r, correct = correct, weight = weight) で:
> The items do not have an equal number of response alternatives, global set to FALSE.

I think the problem originate from the different scales between variables.
How can I do properly analyze FA with different scale?

Comment: If the variables have the `NA` category, does it mean that they have `NA` values? In this case, have they distinct number of `NA`s? I'm not sure if this could be the reason for that error.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully understand the meaning of "NA values" and "distinct number of NAs" because I'm a beginner. Is it that NAs contained in my data are not numeric?

Comment: The first column of your example is `4 2 3 4 1 3`. If there are more observations, it could continue as `4 2 3 4 1 3 3 NA 3 4 2 2 NA 3 NA 4 4 1`, so it would have `NA` values, specifically the number of times `NA` appear is 3. But in the secon column, the number of times there is `NA` could be 2, or 5, for example, so a distinct number of `NA`s. If there were 3 `NA`s in all columns, they would have an equal number of `NA`s. I meant this.

Comment: Is it an error or a warning? Can you share enough of your data to reproduce?

Comment: psych package author at link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27703388/r-fa-parallel-of-psych-package-global-set-to-false doesn't seem to concerned about this message

Comment: >>iago, Thank you, I understood what you meant. Then I thought I could control the problem by the argument of use="complete.obs", doesn't it work?

Comment: >> user20650, I'm afraid I don't know how to share full dataset ... If could can you tell me how to share it?